# Improper integral in an exponential multiplication $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}te^{-2it} \, dt$

Tags: calculus

Improper integral in an exponential form.

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}te^{-2it} \, dt$$

Is there any series  solution for the above integral. what is relation of a bessel function in the form of an exponential form.

Comment: Please see whether this is the integral or not. As Robert Israel says, the integral doesn’t converge.

Answer (score 1):

First, consider the problem of the antiderivative
$$I=\int t\,e^{-2it} \, dt$$ Integrate by parts to get
$$I=e^{-2 i t} \left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{i t}{2}\right)$$ This makes
$$J=\int_{-a}^{a}t\,e^{-2it} \, dt=\frac{i}{2}  (2 a \cos (2 a)-\sin (2 a))$$ which oscilates between $ia$ and $-ia$.

Answer (score 0):

This improper integral diverges.

EDIT: One way to try to "regularize" this divergent integral would be to consider

$$J(c) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty t e^{-2it} e^{-ct^2}\; dt$$
for $c > 0$, and then take the limit as $c \to 0+$.  Now
$$ J(c) = - \frac{i \sqrt{\pi}}{c^{3/2}} e^{-1/c}$$
and
$$ \lim_{c \to 0+} J(c) = 0$$

Comment: can we make this improper integral into a proper integral.

Comment: "Make" in what sense?

Comment: Its output should be finite.

Comment: OK, but how should it be related to the original integral?

Comment: Respected Robert Israel,  "Thanks a Million".